# Pandas add row at index 0 with dummy values

Tags: python, pandas

To this dataframe `df`:

```
        Player   Team  Points  Mean   Price   Value
Gameweek                                                                 
1       Jim  Leeds     4.4   4.40  10.44         0.44
2       Jim  Leeds     8.9   6.65  12.97         2.53
3       Jim  Leeds    -1.8   3.83  10.70        -2.27
```

I need to add a new row at index 0, and fill it with some dummy values, plus an open price. For that I'm trying:

```
df.loc[-1] = [df['Player'].item(), 
              df['Team'].item(),
              0.0, 
              0.0, 
             (df['Price'].item() - df['Value'].item()),
              0.0]  
df.index = df.index +1  # shifting index
df = df.sort_index()  # sorting by index then resseting
```

In order to end up with:

```
        Player   Team  Points  Mean   Price   Value
Gameweek  
0       Jim  Leeds     0.0   0.0   10.00         0.00                                           
1       Jim  Leeds     4.4   4.40  10.44         0.44
2       Jim  Leeds     8.9   6.65  12.97         2.53
3       Jim  Leeds    -1.8   3.83  10.70        -2.27
```

But I'm getting:

```
df.loc[-1] = [df['Player'].item(), 
return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
df.loc[0] = [df['Player'].iloc[0], 
                  df['Team'].iloc[0],
                  0.0, 
                  0.0, 
                 (df['Price'].iloc[0] - df['Value'].iloc[0]),
                  0.0] 
df = df.sort_index()
```

Comment: thanks, but now rows are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 and I need 0, 1, 2, 3. gameweek is the index. possible?

Comment: @8-BitBorges remove the line df.index=df.index+1